# DocuSign connect updates with REST API

Tags: docusignapi

I have been using DocuSign SOAP based API service to parse the XML that DocuSign posts for each recipient/envelope status updates.
Within .net web application, here is how I am parsing the XML.

Using sr As New StreamReader(FileName)
                Dim xml As String = sr.ReadToEnd()

```
            Dim reader As XmlReader = New XmlTextReader(New StringReader(xml))
            Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(DocuSignServ.DocuSignEnvelopeInformation), "http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0")
            Dim envelopeInfo As DocuSignEnvelopeInformation = TryCast(serializer.Deserialize(reader), DocuSignEnvelopeInformation)                
        End Using
```

I would like to know if I can parse the XML with RESTful API here. I could not find a way to convert XML to an object based upon RESTful API.
I tried something like this,

Using sr As New StreamReader(FileName)
                Dim xml As String = sr.ReadToEnd()

```
            Dim reader As XmlReader = New XmlTextReader(New StringReader(xml))
            Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(DocuSign.eSign.Model.EnvelopesInformation), "http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0")
            Dim envelopeInfo As DocuSign.eSign.Model.EnvelopesInformation = TryCast(serializer.Deserialize(reader), DocuSign.eSign.Model.EnvelopesInformation)              
        End Using
```

I am not able to convert the XML to an envelope object here.

Please advise,

Thanks,

Minal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the RESTful API works on different data model and you cannot parse DocuSign Connect XML with RESTful API data model.